# iOS Table cell only returns last row of matching data

Tags: iphone, ios, dynamic, uitableview

I'm trying to insert data into the rows I've created but it only inserts the last row of the data. Could anyone suggest a way to avoid this error? For `cellForRowAtIndexPath` my code is:

```
NSInteger counter = [myArray count];
if (myArray.count > 0){

    for (int i = indexPath.section; i<indexPath.section+1; i++){
        for(int a = 0 ; a < counter; a++) {
            NSDictionary *dic = [counterArray objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *dateString = [dic valueForKey:@"date"];

            NSDictionary *dic2 = [myArray objectAtIndex:a];
            NSString *dateString2 = [dic2 valueForKey:@"date"];

            if ([dateString isEqualToString:dateString2]){
                cell.bookTitle.text = [dic2 objectForKey:@"name"];
            }
        }
    }   
}
return cell;
```

}

So far it looks like this: [image]

And the array actually looks like this:

```
(
  {
    BIBNo = 187883;
    date = "13/08/2012";
    itemSequence = 000010;
    name = "Positive thinking / Susan Quilliam.";
    noOfRenewal = 2;
    number = 000187899;
    status = "Normal Loan";
    time = "24:00";
    type = Loans;
  },
  {
    BIBNo = 161816;
    date = "14/08/2012";
    itemSequence = 000010;
    name = "Malaysian Q & As / compiled by Survey & Interview Department ; illustrations by Exodus.";
    noOfRenewal = 0;
    number = 000161817;
    status = "Normal Loan";
    time = "24:00";
    type = Loans;
  },
  {
    BIBNo = 187882;
    date = "14/08/2012";
    itemSequence = 000010;
    name = "Increasing confidence / Philippa Davies.";
    noOfRenewal = 0;
    number = 000187907;
    status = "Normal Loan";
    time = "24:00";
    type = Loans;
  },
  {
    BIBNo = 291054;
    date = "14/08/2012";
    itemSequence = 000010;
    name = "iPhone application development for IOS 4 / Duncan Campbell.";
    noOfRenewal = 2;
    number = 000291054;
    status = "Normal Loan";
    time = "24:00";
    type = Loans;
  },
  {
    BIBNo = 244441;
    date = "15/08/2012";
    itemSequence = 000010;
    name = "Coach : lessons on the game of life / Michael Lewis.";
    noOfRenewal = 1;
    number = 000244441;
    status = "Normal Loan";
    time = "24:00";
    type = Loans;
  },
  {
    BIBNo = 290408;
    date = "15/08/2012";
    itemSequence = 000010;
    name = "Sams teach yourself iPhone application development in 24 hours / John Ray.";
    noOfRenewal = 3;
    number = 000290408;
    status = "Normal Loan";
    time = "24:00";
    type = Loans;
  }
)
```

Comment: Can you show us the code in the `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` delegate method? (p.s. you can take a screenshot on your iPhone by pressing the power and home button simultaneously or in the iOS simulator by pressing CMD + S)

Comment: You i loop has only one iteration. What is this?

Comment: @basvk updated the code :) oh i'm using a simulator tried using cmd+s but i can't find the image sorry much!

Comment: @dda i used i loop to get the date of the section (3 dates) before comparing it with my a loop which contains the 6 objects. Then if it matches the section date then insert the data into the row

Comment: @XUESNOW: The screenshot should be located on your dashboard (or desktop), something like "iOS Simualator Screenshot xxx.png"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I do not know how to continue with this messy codes I've written, I opened up another question for people to give advice on how to insert sections and rows dynamically, and I redone the codes for my table part and it works perfectly! :)

The link is here : [iOS Using NSDictionary to load data into section and rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673963/ios-using-nsdictionary-to-load-data-into-section-and-rows/11674541#11674541)

In this, I used NSDictionary to insert data dynamically accordingly to the dates. :) Hope it helps anyone with the same problem as me!

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this sort of issue before as well and it is due to the cell identifier: Since it is the same for all cells, it will dequeue a single cell and use that for all rows. I end up solving this via a very hacky and probably not ideal method.. but it works.

I implement the cell identifier like so:

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell-%d-%d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];
```

This guarantees that any given cell that is reused is used for its specific section/row.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this.

Create a NSArray name like mainArray which holds Nsarray Object(Assume these are for sections) and these sections arrays will have NSDictionary Objects(Assume these are rows for each section)

Then you can run the loop like this

```
for(unsigned int counter = 0;counter<[mainArray count];counter++){
  NSArray *sectionArray = [mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
 for(unsigned int counter1 = 0;counter1 < [sectionArray count];counter++ ){
   NSDictionary *mainDataDictionary = [sectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  //Write your code here for a particular cell/row.
 }

}
```

You also need to modify numberOfRowsInSection according to this.

Comment: I have an NSMutableArray which stores all the dictionary objects with the 9 keys but however I do not know how to insert into yet another Dictionary. Therefore, for the sections instead of storing objects with similar date key tgt, i just did some comparison and if the date key is similar, i just remove that object which leaves me with the unique 3 dates that I can use for section count and title

Comment: sorry if my explaination is unclear as I'm not pretty sure am I doing the right thing at all.

Comment: can you send me your code? I will fix it. here is my mail address rahul.vyas.09@gmail.com